# Cannot change the content of a tag for all connected clients

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

Here is my problem:

with socket.io I send a request to the server and from the server I send a request to the client so that when the client receives this one it modifies the text inside my p tag in test for all my clients except that it does not work it modifies it only for me and not for all connected customers.

Here’s my code:

client.js for the frontend:

```
let buttonStart = document.getElementById('startButton');
let text = document.getElementById('text');


buttonStart.addEventListener('click', () => {
    socket.emit('send');
    console.log('send to server');
})

socket.on('send', () => {
    text.innerHTML = 'test';
    console.log('receive on client')
})
```

app.js for the backend:

```
const express = require("express");
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, { /* options */ });

const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));
  
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

httpServer.listen(3000);
console.log('Serveur en ligne...');


io.on("connection", (socket) => {

    socket.on('send', () => {
        socket.emit('send');
        console.log('send to client from server');
    })
});
```

I can’t change the content of this html tag for all my open windows, my clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you should change your server side code in this way

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {

    socket.on('send', () => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('send'); //this send the message back to all the clients except the one that send the original message
        console.log('send to client from server');
    })
});
```

or

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {

    socket.on('send', () => {
        io.of('/').emit('send'); //this send the message to all connected clients
        console.log('send to client from server');
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was almost the solution but thanks to you I realized that instead of putting Io I put socket a stupid mistake. Nice !